# Get the Database name through JDBC with UCanAccess

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

EDIT:

I was testing out this code that I found in another post to look for the database name:

```
public static String getDBname(Connection conn) {
    String result = null;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
            i ++;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

However it just returns me this error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.FeatureNotSupportedException: Feature not supported.
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDatabaseMetadata.getCatalogs(UcanaccessDatabaseMetadata.java:310)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "*Feature not supported*"  seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Btw: to get the "currently selected database" you would need to call `getCatalog()` not `getCatalogs()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did try to use `conn.getCatalog()`, but it just returned me "PUBLIC" which isn't the name of my database.

Answer (score 2):

For UCanAccess, the "database name" is just the name of the .accdb or .mdb file. That can be retrieved by extracting it from the connection URL as returned by

```java
conn.getMetaData().getURL()
```

e.g.,

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Public/UCanAccessTest.accdb;memory=false
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response. I know I can just get it using substrings from that result, but I just want to know if there's a simpler method I can use to get the Database name with just "UCanAccessTest"

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. As you noticed, `Connection#getCatalog()` always returns "PUBLIC", which relates to the HSQLDB backing database and not to the Access database itself.

Comment: You're right Gord. And I should implement something tricky before exposing a meaningful catalog name as  above mentioned, i.e., it should actually work as catalog. Not in this stage, please use the substrings;-)